# Detecting family of $[\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set}]$

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

I am trying to prove that $\{C(A,-)\mid A\in \text{ob}\mathcal{C}\}$ is a detecting family for the functor category $[\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set}]$. For that, I need to check that taking a natural transformation $\alpha \colon F\longrightarrow G$, if $\beta \colon C(A,-) \longrightarrow G$ factors uniquely as $\beta= \alpha \circ \gamma$ for some $$\gamma \colon C(A,-)\longrightarrow F$$ natural transformation, then $\alpha$ is bijective.

By Yoneda's lemma, $\beta$ corresponds bijectively to an element of $GA$; more concretely, to $y=\beta_{A}(1_{A})$ and $\gamma$ corresponds bijectively to $x=\gamma_{A}(1_{A})$. Since $\alpha \circ \gamma=\beta$, we have that $\alpha_{A}(x)=y$.

However, I do not know how to conclude that $\alpha_A$ is an isomorphism.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept of detecting family. The requirement  that _if *each $\beta$* factors through $\alpha$ then $\alpha_A$ must be an isomorphism, is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that (for each $A$) each $\beta$, equivalently element of $GA$, gives rise to a *unique* $\gamma$, equivalently element of $FA$, means we can Skolemize to get a function $\delta_A:GA\to FA$ that witnesses this statement. This will be a pre-inverse to $\alpha_A$ by definition, i.e. $\alpha_A(\delta_A(y))=y$, which makes $\alpha_A$ a surjection. The uniqueness constraint essentially *is* the statement that $\alpha_A$ is an injection. So $\alpha_A$ is a bijection for each $A$, and a natural transformation that's an isomorphism for each component is a natural isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand why is it possible to get the function $\delta_{A}$. If $\beta_{A}$ were surjective, by noticing that $\alpha_{A}(\gamma_{A})=\beta_{A}$ I understand it, but otherwise? Thank you and sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: $\delta_A$ is a function that takes in $\beta$ and produces $\gamma$. However, as you point out in the question, by Yoneda we can identify each $\beta$ and $\gamma$ with elements of $GA$ and $FA$ respectively. My answer talks directly in terms of those elements. We have such a $\delta_A$ for each object $A$ and these will form a natural transformation inverse to $\alpha$. Whenever we have $\forall x\in X.\exists y\in Y.P(x,y)$ we can introduce a Skolem function producing $\forall x\in X.P(x,f(x))$. $\delta_A$ is the Skolem function for $\forall\beta.\exists\gamma.\beta=\alpha\circ\gamma$.